# Dynamic transpose for unknown row value into column name on postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have table such:

| customer_number | label | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | address | St. John 1A |
| 1 | phone | 111111111 |
| 1 | email | john@cena.com |
| 2 | address | St. Marry 231A |
| 2 | phone | 222222222 |
| 2 | email | please@marry.me |

I want new table or view so it's become:

| customer_number | address | phone | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | St. John 1A | 111111111 | john@cena.com |
| 2 | St. Marry 231A | 222222222 | please@marry.me |

but in the future there are possibility to add different label, for example there might be new label called `occupation`.

**Important to note**, I don't know the value of the label column, so it's should iterate to any value inside that column.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a "dynamic" pivot as the number, names and data types of all columns of a query must be known to the database *before* the query is actually executed (i.e. at parse time).

I find aggregating stuff into a JSON easier to deal with.

```
select customer_number,
       jsonb_object_agg(label, value) as props
from the_table
group by customer_number
```

If your frontend can deal with JSON values directly, you can stop here.

If you really need a view with one column per attribute, you can them from the JSON value:

```
select customer_number, 
       props ->> 'address' as address,
       props ->> 'phone' as phone,
       props ->> 'email' as email
from (       
  select customer_number,
         jsonb_object_agg(label, value) as props
  from the_table
  group by customer_number
) t
```

I find this a bit easier to manage when new attributes are added.

---

If you need a view with all labels, you can create a stored procedure to dynamically create it. If the number of different labels doesn't change too often, this might be a solution:

```
create procedure create_customer_view() 
as
$$
declare
  l_sql text;
  l_columns text;
begin
  select string_agg(distinct format('(props ->> %L) as %I', label, label), ', ')
    into l_columns
  from the_table;
  
  l_sql := 
    'create view customer_properties as 
     select customer_number, '||l_columns||' 
     from (
      select customer_number, jsonb_object_agg(label, value) as props
       from the_table 
       group by customer_number 
     ) t';
  execute l_sql;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then create the view using:

```
call create_customer_view();
```

And in your code just use:

```sql
select *
from customer_properties;
```

You can schedule that procedure to run in regular intervals (e.g. through a `cron` job on Linux)

Comment: So I must know every possible `label` value?

Comment: @F.Suyuti: yes, but you can create a procedure to dynamically create a view with the current labels. See my edit

Comment: your procedure works like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally-speaking SQL is not good at pivotting dynamically.

Here is a query that will pivot the data for you. However, it is not dynamic i.e. if a future `occupation` label was added then you would have to change the query. Not sure whether that is acceptable or not :

```
select customer_number,
max(value) filter (where label='address') as address,
max(value) filter (where label='phone') as phone,
max(value) filter (where label='email') as email
from your_customer_table
group by customer_number
```

Bit of an assumption that you are running Postgres 9.4 or better here so that the `filter` function is supported. If not then it can be re-worked using `case` statements :

```
select customer_number,
max(case when label='address' then value else null end) as address,
max(case when label='phone' then value else null end) as phone,
max(case when label='email' then value else null end) as email
from your_customer_table
group by customer_number
```

Answer (score -1):

I used cross apply to solve this problem ..
Here is my query

```
select distinct tb9.customer_number, tb9_2.*
from Table_9 tb9 cross apply
     (select max(case when tb9_2.[label] like '%address%' then [value] end) as [address],
             max(case when tb9_2.[label] like '%phone%' then [value] end) as [phone],
             max(case when tb9_2.[label] like '%email%' then [value] end) as [email]
      from Table_9 tb9_2
      where tb9.customer_number = tb9_2.customer_number
     ) tb9_2;
```

Comment: That's not valid for Postgres (or standard SQL)

Comment: I don't pay attention to Postgres, but it works on MS SQL @a_horse_with_no_name , it could be the second way after the answer above. Thank u

Comment: For Postgres you need to replace the non-standard `cross apply` with the standard compliant `cross join lateral` and you need to remove the non-standard square brackets around the column names.